# pull hook after pushing to a git repo

Tags: git, githooks, git-post-receive

When one pushes to a specific branch in the git repository I want it to be automatically pulled to the web server directory on the same machine.

It looks like a post-receive hook would be in order but I haven't been able to find a good example of how to write such a hook. Can someone point me in the right direction?